# Re-index items in DSpace 6.2 after updating through REST

Tags: solr, dspace

We are trying to build an application to provide bulk editing of item metadata ingested in DSpace, using the REST API. The update operations are being reflected in the DSpace UI. However the metadata remains unchanged in Solr, unless we run index-discovery. Since we intend to work with a large amount of data, running index-discovery everytime a metadata is edited, would be expensive. Could someone suggest a workaround/solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You could trigger an item update in the Java class of the REST endpoint.

For example:
In method addItemMetadata of java class org.dspace.rest.ItemsResource which represents the /items REST endpoint you could add the following line after the item metadata has been changed:

```
itemService.update(context, dspaceItem);
```

This line of code triggers an index update for that specific item.

This is what the complete addItemMetadata method will look like after the above change:

```
@POST
@Path("/{item_id}/metadata")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public Response addItemMetadata(@PathParam("item_id") String itemId, List<org.dspace.rest.common.MetadataEntry> metadata,
        @QueryParam("userIP") String user_ip, @QueryParam("userAgent") String user_agent,
        @QueryParam("xforwardedfor") String xforwardedfor, @Context HttpHeaders headers, @Context HttpServletRequest request)
        throws WebApplicationException
{

    log.info("Adding metadata to item(id=" + itemId + ").");
    org.dspace.core.Context context = null;

    try
    {
        context = createContext();
        org.dspace.content.Item dspaceItem = findItem(context, itemId, org.dspace.core.Constants.WRITE);

        writeStats(dspaceItem, UsageEvent.Action.UPDATE, user_ip, user_agent, xforwardedfor, headers, request, context);

        for (MetadataEntry entry : metadata)
        {
            // TODO Test with Java split
            String data[] = mySplit(entry.getKey()); // Done by my split, because of java split was not function.
            if ((data.length >= 2) && (data.length <= 3))
            {
                itemService.addMetadata(context, dspaceItem, data[0], data[1], data[2], entry.getLanguage(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }

        itemService.update(context, dspaceItem);
        context.complete();

    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        processException("Could not write metadata to item(id=" + itemId + "), SQLException. Message: " + e, context);
    }
    catch (ContextException e)
    {
        processException("Could not write metadata to item(id=" + itemId + "), ContextException. Message: " + e.getMessage(),
                context);
    } catch (AuthorizeException e) {
        processException("Could not update item(id=" + itemId + "), AuthorizeException. Message: " + e.getMessage(),
                context);
    } finally
    {
        processFinally(context);
    }

    log.info("Metadata to item(id=" + itemId + ") were successfully added.");
    return Response.status(Status.OK).build();
}
```

Comment: We actually reverted to an older version of DSpace (5.6), because we didn't really want to do any code level modifications in DSpace. Hope this issue is fixed in subsequent versions